# Features from GH4-WOR missing in GH5

Tags: guitar-hero-warriors-rock

I've been playing Guitar Hero 4 Warriors of Rock on XBox 360 for a bit of time now, and have recently upgraded to Guitar Hero 5. Although I am kinda happy with the game overall,  there are a couple of handy features from GH4 that appear to be missing, or maybe I just haven't found how to activate them yet (I've been browsing the options a couple of times, but it didn't help).

The features I'm missing most are :

- being able to restart a song immediately after it ended by pressing the yellow button
- getting the song selection cursor to stay in position after a song ends, instead of winding back to the beginning of the song list
- alternating between the score and difficulty tabs in the song selection screen
- jumping through the song selection screen using the yellow button (besides, screen-by-screen navigation using yellow+up/down is a pain to use with the drums since it means I have to reach for the D-pad, which is quite uncomfortable to do while holding the sticks)

Is there any way to activate any of these features in guitar hero 5 ?

I am most interested in keeping the cursor at the last played song since starting from the beginning of the list every time makes it kinda frustrating to try to play several songs in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the reason some features from Guitar hero:WOR aren't in Guitar Hero 5  is because WOR came out *after* Guitar Hero 5, it's actually Guitar Hero 6 (4 was World Tour). These are new features that were added, not old ones omitted.

Guitar Hero World Tour (4) came out October 26, 2008
Guitar Hero 5 came out September 1, 2009
Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock (6) came out September 24 2010

Comment: Oh, right... my bad. I have no idea why I was so sure WOR was the 4th in the series